# Celery on Windows without MQ

Tags: windows, celery

I do have an App running on linux using Celery/RabbitMQ, the setup works fine.

But now I have to develop some new features and the developing machine I have available is Windows7 with no admin rights, so I can't install Rabbit or Redis server.

There is some way to emulate this so I can execute this app (Flask by the way), on my windows machine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager):

> If this is True, all tasks will be executed locally by blocking until
>   the task returns. apply_async() and Task.delay() will return an
>   EagerResult instance, which emulates the API and behavior of
>   AsyncResult, except the result is already evaluated.
>
> That is, tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the
>   queue.

Comment: I was happy with my own solution, but now I feel shame about that. Thanks, this works nicely....

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to answer my own question but if someone found this while looking for a way to emulate the presence of celery when it is not in there here is what I did:

Since I'm using Flask I already had a modified celery class to share context, now I had a second `make_celery` function to be used when I need the emulation.

```
if usefake == True:
    #this is a fake task! actualy task will run in same thread of caller
    def make_celery(app):
        class FakeCelery(object):
            def task(self, func):
                class FakeTask(object):
                    def __init__(self, f):
                        self.f = f
                    def delay(self, *args, **kwargs):
                        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
                return FakeTask(func)
        return FakeCelery()
else:
    #this is the production maker which share the context with the task
    def make_celery(app):
        celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
        celery.conf.update(app.config)
        TaskBase = celery.Task
        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True
            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                with app.app_context():
                    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        celery.Task = ContextTask
        return celery

celery = make_celery(app)
```

both have the same usage:

```
@celery.task
def mytask(a, b):
    return a+b

mytask.delay(1, 2)
```

As you can see I always use `delay` only, so the other task functions like `get` is not implemented but can be done.

I don't think this is a nice solution, but solved my problem for now. Any other solution will be wellcome.